# spaces in url ftp client in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, ftp

I use ftp Node.js and I'm able to read files and folders but only folders in their URLs there is no spaces.

this **works**:

```
var ftp = require('ftp');
var path = "app/LaundryMachine";
var client = new ftp();
    //connect properties
    var config = {
        host: '***.net',
        port: 21,
        user: '***',
        password: '***'
    };
    client.on('ready', function () {
            client.list(path, function (err, list) {
                if (err) throw err;
                for (var i in list) {
                    console.log(list[i].name);
                }

                client.end();
            });
    });
    client.connect(config);
```

but, if the var path have space it's **not work**.

```
var path = "app/Laundry Machine";
```

I try to put %20 or +, but still not.

Comment: Have you tried using quotes around the path? `var path = "\"app/Laundry Machine\"";`

Comment: yes. but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use listSafe method instead of list.

From [npmjs.org/package/ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp#optional-standard-commands-rfc-959)

"This is useful for servers that do not handle characters like spaces and quotes in directory names well for the LIST command."